# Does negative correlation survive monotone transformation?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, correlation, expected-value

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two non-negative random variables and be negative correlated, i.e., 
$$\mathbb{E}[XY] \leq \mathbb{E}[X]\mathbb{E}[Y].$$
Let $h(\cdot)$ and $g(\cdot)$ be two non-negative, monotone increasing functions. Do we have
$h(X)$ and $g(Y)$ being negative correlated as well? Intuitively this quite makes sense to me..

Comment: Counterexample: Consider the discrete uniform distribution on $\{(0,1),(0.9,0),(1,0)\}$, and let $h$ be the monotone function that maps $\{0,0.9,1\}$ to $\{0,0.1,1\}$.

Comment: @Rahul Thanks. Isn't it still being negative correlated after the transformation, because the expectation of the product is still zero?

Comment: Whoops, typo: the third point should be $(1,1)$.

Comment: @Rahul Hi Rahul, your ideas make sense to me. Thanks so much. However, we may still need a little bit of work as after the transformation they are still negative correlated, because $h(Y) = Y$ thus $Cov(h(X),h(Y)) = -\frac{2.3}{3}$. I'll think more about this. Many thanks.

Comment: One of us must be making a mistake. I get covariances $-0.8/9$ and $0.8/9$ before and after transformation by $h$ respectively. $E[XY]=1/3$ and $E[Y]=2/3$ in both cases, but $E[X]$ changes from $1.9/3$ to $1.1/3$. It's also easy to visualize the change in correlation if you plot the data and consider the best fitting line.

Comment: @Rahul Sorry my fault. Thanks so much, Rahul, you are correct.

Answer (score 1):

Copying from Rahul's comment since it answers the question:

No. Counterexample: Consider the discrete uniform distribution on {(0,1),(0.9,0),(1,1)}, and let h be the monotone function that maps {0,0.9,1} to  {0,0.1,1}.